# glfw3.dll not found system error when running the code

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-code, c++17, glfw

I have set GLFW in Visual Studio Code (code editor, not an IDE). When I run the code, it gives me a  system error:- glfw3.dll not found.

Here is the code which I copied from the documentation of GLFW:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my tasks.json file:-

```
    {
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                "/Zi",
                "/EHsc",
                "/nologo",
                "/I${workspaceFolder}\\glfw\\include",
                "/Fe:",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp",

                "opengl32.lib",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\glfw\\lib-vc2019\\glfw3dll.lib"

            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: cl.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code it self, you need to setup [your visual studio project correctly](http://www.mcihanozer.com/tips/setting-up-libraries/setting-up-glfw-for-visual-studio/) Also learn about Dynamic Link Libraries [DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-libraries) since you'll faced with the same issues with GLEW and the rest, so you should know hot it works

Comment: As well as if you have an executable - you DLL's should be visible to it. Check [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order)

Comment: Thanks a lot, the documentation on "Setting Up GLFW for Visual Studio", which you posted really helped me!

Answer (score -1):

You need to link the library to your linker. Go to project settings, Linker, and add the path to additional libraries. The path could be the lib folder of vcpkg.